# Issue with Scroll bar in Highcharts/Highstock chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I had a requirement of having vertical scroll in a bar chart and have implemented it using Highstock Charts.

I could achieve it. Appreciate Highstock chart, for plotting the chart dynamically on scroll, but have lots of issues when the data is huge.

- The bars are getting overlapped
- axis ticks are disappearing, instead tick numbers are only shown
- plotting and performance are inconsistent.

Appreciate, if anyone provide me a solution or work around for this issue.

Thanks!!

[Fiddle to play](http://jsfiddle.net/e9n12hqn/1/)

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        marginLeft: 150
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Most popular ideas by April 2016'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api">UserVoice</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        min: 0,
        max: 4,
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: true
        },
        tickLength: 0
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 1200,
        title: {
            text: 'Votes',
            align: 'high'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Votes',
        data: [
            ["Gantt chart", 1000],
            ["Autocalculation and plotting of trend lines", 575],
            ["Allow navigator to have multiple data series", 523],
            ["Implement dynamic font size", 427],
            ["Multiple axis alignment control", 399],
            ["Stacked area (spline etc) in irregular datetime series", 309],
            ["Adapt chart height to legend height", 278],
            ["Export charts in excel sheet", 239],
            ["Toggle legend box", 235],
            ["Venn Diagram", 203],
            ["Add ability to change Rangeselector position", 182],
            ["Draggable legend box", 157],
            ["Sankey Diagram", 149],
            ["Add Navigation bar for Y-Axis in Highstock", 144],
            ["Grouped x-axis", 143],
            ["ReactJS plugin", 137],
            ["3D surface charts", 134],
            ["Draw lines over a stock chart, for analysis purpose", 118],
            ["Data module for database tables", 118],
            ["Draggable points", 117],
            ["Gantt chart", 1000],
            ["Autocalculation and plotting of trend lines", 575],
            ["Allow navigator to have multiple data series", 523],
            ["Implement dynamic font size", 427],
            ["Multiple axis alignment control", 399],
            ["Stacked area (spline etc) in irregular datetime series", 309],
            ["Adapt chart height to legend height", 278],
            ["Export charts in excel sheet", 239],
            ["Toggle legend box", 235],
            ["Venn Diagram", 203],
            ["Add ability to change Rangeselector position", 182],
            ["Draggable legend box", 157],
            ["Sankey Diagram", 149],
            ["Add Navigation bar for Y-Axis in Highstock", 144],
            ["Grouped x-axis", 143],
            ["ReactJS plugin", 137],
            ["3D surface charts", 134],
            ["Draw lines over a stock chart, for analysis purpose", 118],
            ["Data module for database tables", 118],
            ["Draggable points", 117],
            ["Gantt chart", 1000],
            ["Autocalculation and plotting of trend lines", 575],
            ["Allow navigator to have multiple data series", 523],
            ["Implement dynamic font size", 427],
            ["Multiple axis alignment control", 399],
            ["Stacked area (spline etc) in irregular datetime series", 309],
            ["Adapt chart height to legend height", 278],
            ["Export charts in excel sheet", 239],
            ["Toggle legend box", 235],
            ["Venn Diagram", 203],
            ["Add ability to change Rangeselector position", 182],
            ["Draggable legend box", 157],
            ["Sankey Diagram", 149],
            ["Add Navigation bar for Y-Axis in Highstock", 144],
            ["Grouped x-axis", 143],
            ["ReactJS plugin", 137],
            ["3D surface charts", 134],
            ["Draw lines over a stock chart, for analysis purpose", 118],
            ["Data module for database tables", 118],
            ["Draggable points", 117],
            ["Gantt chart", 1000],
            ["Autocalculation and plotting of trend lines", 575],
            ["Allow navigator to have multiple data series", 523],
            ["Implement dynamic font size", 427],
            ["Multiple axis alignment control", 399],
            ["Stacked area (spline etc) in irregular datetime series", 309],
            ["Adapt chart height to legend height", 278],
            ["Export charts in excel sheet", 239],
            ["Toggle legend box", 235],
            ["Venn Diagram", 203],
            ["Add ability to change Rangeselector position", 182],
            ["Draggable legend box", 157],
            ["Sankey Diagram", 149],
            ["Add Navigation bar for Y-Axis in Highstock", 144],
            ["Grouped x-axis", 143],
            ["ReactJS plugin", 137],
            ["3D surface charts", 134],
            ["Draw lines over a stock chart, for analysis purpose", 118],
            ["Data module for database tables", 118],
            ["Draggable points", 117],
            ["Gantt chart", 1000],
            ["Autocalculation and plotting of trend lines", 575],
            ["Allow navigator to have multiple data series", 523],
            ["Implement dynamic font size", 427],
            ["Multiple axis alignment control", 399],
            ["Stacked area (spline etc) in irregular datetime series", 309],
            ["Adapt chart height to legend height", 278],
            ["Export charts in excel sheet", 239],
            ["Toggle legend box", 235],
            ["Venn Diagram", 203],
            ["Add ability to change Rangeselector position", 182],
            ["Draggable legend box", 157],
            ["Sankey Diagram", 149],
            ["Add Navigation bar for Y-Axis in Highstock", 144],
            ["Grouped x-axis", 143],
            ["ReactJS plugin", 137],
            ["3D surface charts", 134],
            ["Draw lines over a stock chart, for analysis purpose", 118],
            ["Data module for database tables", 118],
            ["Draggable points", 117]
        ]
    }]
});
```

```html
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 320px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if it is a bug or not. However, you can set [series.cropTreshold](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.cropThreshold) to some big number. If you use categories with the same name, you should also set [axis.uniqueNames](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.uniqueNames) to false.

```
  series: [{
    cropThreshold: 100000,
    name: 'Votes',
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/rft0t40L/

The other possibility can be setting categories array and map the points to `[category-number, value]`.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/rft0t40L/1/